# Set FullScreen Background into Wordpress site?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles

i want to put full screen background into my [personal Wordpress site](https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/), and having some issue with it. I tryed to insert fullscreen background in this way:

```
body {
background-image: url(https://testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Backround5.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

but when load the site, it shown background in full size for second and after that back , again to corners background.. How to set background image to show in full size, including page content? Affected [URL](https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do a bit better? According to your CSS, it looks like you're trying to set the background to the whole body of the page, which is what's actually going on. Your page content may have additional backgrounds which are being displayed over-top of the body background (for example this is happening with your slider).

Comment: i want background to be into entire site i meen entire page, not only outside page content..  Currently background goes to sides and where is content is black. i want background to goes also there. https://i.imgur.com/jbETeHZ.png?1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, the reason why this is happening is because you have other elements that have backgrounds which are being rendered over-top of your body.

There's a background:black being assigned to a number of your elements. I've done a live inspection and edited a number of them to have background:transparent !important, to override the setting in order to display the background from the body.

You will need to go through your site, much like I did in screenshot provided below, and you'll have to find out which elements have a background, and set their background to transparent.

[image]

What I've done to remove the backgrounds from those two elements on your homepage is:

A)

```
#media_image-2 {
    background: transparent !important;
}

.widget-odd .widget-last .widget-first .widget-1 .def-block .widget .clr .widget_media_image {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

B)

```
.ult_tabs .ult_tab_min_contain.tabanimate {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

Once you've eliminated all of the backgrounds on the elements in front of your body, you will be able to see your main background just like in the screenshot provided.

**EDIT (In addition to previous solution)**:

If the intention is to create a full-parallax style background where the background is more or less fixed in a position regardless of where you're scrolling... add this to the CSS of your body:

```
background: url(yourbackground.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed !important;
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover !important;
-o-background-size: cover !important;
background-size: cover !important;
```

Comment: Image have lines and its not in full size.. 

https://i.imgur.com/sLObomP.jpg

How to get that in full size without, repeating..

Comment: See edited solution. I believe this is what you were trying to explain.

Comment: Something is not fine. After inserting your code all background is white.

Comment: ...You need to properly source your actual background... I don't know the actual URL of your background.

Comment: Now is showing fine, but page elements are still black.. This is the code i used:

`body {
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: #C2C2C2;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-family: "Tahoma", Helvetica, Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 background: url(https://touchdowner.cz/digital-products/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Backround5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed !important;
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover !important;
-o-background-size: cover !important;
background-size: cover !important;
     background-size: cover !important;
}`

Comment: Seems fine after add your first CSS.

Comment: The solution is a 2 part solution Joe. You need to have both CSS things in your website. The first CSS is to remove the black from the elements, and the second set of CSS is to adjust your background. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this on body for background

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

and for others elements

```
.ult_tabs .ult_tab_min_contain.tabanimate{
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```